# How can a parent process send socket/server object to child process in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Consider:

```
// Parent

var child = require('child_process').fork('child.js');

// Open up the server object and send the handle.
var server = require('net').createServer();
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.end('handled by parent');
});
server.listen(1337, function() {
  child.send('server', server);
});

//Child
process.on('message', function(m, server) {
  if (m === 'server') {
    server.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.end('handled by child');
    });
  }
});
```

As shown in above example, parents sends server object to child processes so that even a child had handle some of client connection requests.

How is it achieved in Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [Node.js cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works):

> When you call `server.listen(...)` in a worker, it serializes the arguments and passes the request to the master process. If the master process already has a listening server matching the worker's requirements, then it passes the handle to the worker. If it does not already have a listening server matching that requirement, then it will create one, and pass the handle to the child.

Complete example from [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html):

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it's an HTTP server
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

Comment: Hi Linus, Can u throw some light on how server object is being passed to child process in the example given by me ?

Comment: This seems to be the relevant [parts of the source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/c668185adde3a474585a11f172b8387e270ec23b/lib/cluster.js#L523-558).

Answer (score 5):

Here is [what node does when `process.send` is called with a `handle` argument](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/cbff8f091c22fb1df6b238c7a1b9145db950fa65/lib/child_process.js#L406-L452).

And after reading that, [the `handleConversion` function](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/cbff8f091c22fb1df6b238c7a1b9145db950fa65/lib/child_process.js#L80-L192) is also interesting to read.

I don't fully understand it yet, but I think essentially the state of the socket/server is serialized and passed between master/worker using IPC. Maybe the state being passed around is enough for each process to bind itself to the socket? Or maybe the parent is keeping a registry of children who can handle any given socket, so once a new connection comes in for some socket, it is sent to a child that registered for it. That part I am less sure about.

Answer (score 4):

This is now [possible](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_a_socket_object), but only if you're using the `net` module, which you are.

`child.send('socket', socket);` Use the second parameter to send:

And to receive from child process:

```
process.on('message', function(m, socket) {
   if (m === 'socket') {
       console.log(socket); // Net socket object here
   }
});
```